# Acceptance Test and CI

Tags: continuous-integration, acceptance-testing

We have 3 types of tests, unit, functional and acceptance.

The first 2 can be run with phpunit or other tools on top of it like codeception. So in CI the deploy script will run all these tests and if one fail build will fail and merge request will be cancelled.

But in CI deploy script how to run acceptance tests? These tests need to be run in browser in an already deployed build. Is there a workaround for that? Maybe run acceptance tests after build succeeds? 
But then revert will be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

You can parallelize the test jobs as advised in every CI/CD [pipeline](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/architecting-continuous-delivery).

> But in CI deploy script how to run acceptance tests?

For this you will need dedicated Test infrastructure, like available browsers on the server. After build step is successful - run all Test steps.

The parallel jobs can be setup like this:

[image]